How to extract the values in ansible from the query_results of a SQL select?
I created a simple select to test the result of a MySQL installation in an ansible playbook:
 - name: Simple select query to db playground
   community.mysql.mysql_query:
     login_db: {{ database name }}
     login_user: {{ login_user }}
     login_password: {{ login_password }}
     query: SELECT * FROM equipment;
   register: r_query

I register the result of that task into a variable r_query.
When I debug the query_result of this variable I get the following:
ok: [db01] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            {
                "color": "white",
                "id": 2,
                "quant": 1,
                "type": "shark"
            },
            {
                "color": "grey",
                "id": 4,
                "quant": 2,
                "type": "whale"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
ok: [db02] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            {
                "color": "white",
                "id": 2,
                "quant": 1,
                "type": "shark"
            },
            {
                "color": "grey",
                "id": 4,
                "quant": 2,
                "type": "whale"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
ok: [db03] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            {
                "color": "white",
                "id": 2,
                "quant": 1,
                "type": "shark"
            },
            {
                "color": "grey",
                "id": 4,
                "quant": 2,
                "type": "whale"
            }
        ]
    ]
}

I already checked some explanations how to extract the single values but nothing worked yet.
How can I access the second color value of the result of the first machine db01?

Let's create the inventory below and change the second colors to red, green, and blue for testing
shell> cat hosts
all:
  hosts:
    db01:
      r_query:
        - - {color: white, id: 2, quant: 1, type: shark}
          - {color: red, id: 4, quant: 2, type: whale}
    db02:
      r_query:
        - - {color: white, id: 2, quant: 1, type: shark}
          - {color: green, id: 4, quant: 2, type: whale}
    db03:
      r_query:
        - - {color: white, id: 2, quant: 1, type: shark}
          - {color: blue, id: 4, quant: 2, type: whale}

See hostvars. This dictionary keeps all variables for all hosts. For example,
    - debug:
        var: hostvars[inventory_hostname].r_query.0.1.color

gives
ok: [db01] => 
  hostvars[inventory_hostname].r_query.0.1.color: red
ok: [db02] => 
  hostvars[inventory_hostname].r_query.0.1.color: green
ok: [db03] => 
  hostvars[inventory_hostname].r_query.0.1.color: blue

To "access the second color value of the result of the first machine db01"
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.db01.r_query.0.1.color

gives
ok: [db01] => 
  hostvars.db01.r_query.0.1.color: red
ok: [db02] => 
  hostvars.db01.r_query.0.1.color: red
ok: [db03] => 
  hostvars.db01.r_query.0.1.color: red

A host doesn't need hostvars to access its variables, of course
    - debug:
        var: r_query.0.1.color

gives
ok: [db01] => 
  r_query.0.1.color: red
ok: [db02] => 
  r_query.0.1.color: green
ok: [db03] => 
  r_query.0.1.color: blue



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: hostvars[inventory_hostname].r_query.0.1.color

    - debug:
        var: hostvars.db01.r_query.0.1.color

    - debug:
        var: r_query.0.1.color


hostvars also help you to create reports for all hosts in a play. For example,
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for h in ansible_play_hosts %}
          {{ h }}: {{ hostvars[h].r_query.0.1.color }}
          {% endfor %}
      run_once: true

gives
  msg: |-
    db01: red
    db02: green
    db03: blue


You can extract certain attributes and declare a dictionary. For example,
  colors_2nd: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts |
                  zip(ansible_play_hosts |
                  map('extract', hostvars, ['r_query', 0, 1, 'color']))) }}"

makes the access to the second color value trivial
  colors_2nd:
    db01: red
    db02: green
    db03: blue


To create the dictionary, you can also use Jinja. The declaration below gives the same result
  colors_2nd: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for h in ansible_play_hosts %}
    {{ h }}: {{ hostvars[h].r_query.0.1.color }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}


